# iTextSharp - Checkbox wont print

Tags: itext

I am new to iTextSharp, and would appreciate some help.

I am creating some checkboxes, an example of the code is below:

```
    var rec = new Rectangle(PageSize.A4);
    var fs = new FileStream(path, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None);
    var doc = new Document(rec);
    var writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, fs);

PdfFormField checkbox1 = PdfFormField.CreateCheckBox(writer);
            checkbox1.SetWidget(new Rectangle(524, 600, 540, 616), PdfAnnotation.HIGHLIGHT_INVERT);
            checkbox1.ValueAsName = ("Off");
            checkbox1.AppearanceState = ("Off");
            checkbox1.FieldName = ("UsersNo");
            checkbox1.SetAppearance(PdfAnnotation.APPEARANCE_NORMAL, "Off", chkOff);
            checkbox1.SetAppearance(PdfAnnotation.APPEARANCE_NORMAL, "On", chkOn);
            writer.AddAnnotation(checkbox1);
```

Everything looks great and is working well, until it comes to printing the actual PDF, when I click on File and Print, the checkboxes do not show in the print preview, and also do not print.

Is there anything anyone could point me to?

Appreciate the help in advance.

Jason

Comment: Can you share the PDF file? Put it on some public file sharing service so that we can take a look at it.

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways to create a check box.

1. There is the easy way, using the `RadioCheckField` class.
2. There is the hard way, using the `PdfFormField` class.

For some reason you have chosen the hard way.

You are now complaining that the visibility is set to *"Show on screen, not in print"* instead of *"Show on screen and in print"*.

- The former (*"Show on screen, not in print"*) is the default visibility setting when you create a check box the hard way. It corresponds with no flags being set.
- The latter (*"Show on screen and in print"*) is the default when creating a check box the easy way. In this case, the following flag is set automatically for your convenience.

As you have chosen the hard way to create a check box, you need to add the line that add the "Print flag" to your code yourself:

```
checkbox1.Flags = PdfAnnotation.FLAGS_PRINT;
```

Answer (score 0):

**Its working for me:**
[image]

```
    Paragraph p = new Paragraph("");
    PdfFont font = PdfFontFactory.createFont(StandardFonts.ZAPFDINGBATS);
    Text chunk = new Text("4").setFont(font).setFontSize(14);
    p.add(chunk);
    Table tableSection = new Table(1);

    p.setFontColor(WebColors.getRGBColor("#ffffff"));
    Cell cell = new Cell();
    cell.add(p);
    cell.setPaddingLeft(10f);
    cell.setPaddingRight(10f);
    cell.setBackgroundColor(WebColors.getRGBColor("#000000"));
    tableSection.addCell(cell);
    document.add(tableSection);
```